# ISNULL/COALESCE for multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, coalesce

Consider the following data model:

***Customers***

```
CustNum | First Name | Last Name
  555        John         Doe
```

***CustomerAddresses***

```
CustNum | ShippingAddress|     Line1      |  Line2  |   City  | State |  Zip    
  555   |     ADD1       |   333 A Dr.    | Apt. 10 | Dallas  |  TX   | 11345  
  555   |     ADD2       |   111 B St.    |  NULL   | Miami   |  FL   | 22222
  555   |     WXYZ       |  123 Main St.  |  NULL   | Detroit |  MI   | 99998
```

***OrderHeader***

```
OrdNum | CustNum | OrderTotal |     Line1     | Line2 |   City  | State|  Zip
 1000  |   555   |   67.00    | 123 Main St.  | Ste 1 | Detroit |  MI  | 99998
```

***OrderLine***

```
OrderNo  | Item  |  Price  | ShippingAddress  
 1000    | X123  |  32.00  |     ADD1
 1000    | Y234  |  25.00  |     ADD2
 1000    | ZZZZ  |  10.00  |     NULL
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between Customers and CustomerAddresses.
Each OrderHeader, instead of a key relationship to the CustomerAddresses table, stores the address used for shipping in the Line1, Line2, City, State, and Zip fields.
In addition, it's possible to select a shipping address in the OrderLine table that overrides the address stored in the OrderHeader.
I'm trying to come up with a query to return data in the following format, to generate a list of mailing labels:
***MailingLabels***

```
OrderNo  | Item  |     Line1      |  Line2  |   City  | State |  Zip     
 1000    | X123  |   333 A Dr.    | Apt. 10 | Dallas  |  TX   | 11345
 1000    | Y234  |   111 B St.    |  NULL   | Miami   |  FL   | 22222
 1000    | ZZZZ  |  123 Main St.  |  NULL   | Detroit |  MI   | 99998
```

Basically, if the OrderLine record has a ShippingAddress value, I want to return the corresponding address from the CustomerAddresses table.
If it is NULL, then I want to return the Line1, Line2, City, State, and Zip values stored in the OrderHeader table.
The problem is, when I use COALESCE or ISNULL, it's possible to return incorrect results.  Here's my query:

```
SELECT OH.OrderNo, Item, ISNULL(CA.Line1, OH.Line1), ISNULL(CA.Line2, OH.Line2),  
       ISNULL(CA.City, OH.City), ISNULL(CA.State, OH.State), ISNULL(CA.Zip, OH.Zip)
FROM   OrderHeader OH
JOIN   OrderLine OL
ON     OH.OrderNo = OL.OrderNo
LEFT JOIN   CustomerAddress CA
ON     OL.CustNum = CA.CustNum
AND    OL.ShippingAddress = CA.ShippingAddress
```

With the above query, if the Line2 field is defined for the OrderHeader, but the ShippingAddress is defined in OrderLine, it's possible to return a mixed address for the Y234 item:

```
OrderNo | Item |   Line1   |  Line2  |   City  | State |  Zip            
1000    | Y234 | 111 B St. |  Ste 1  |  Miami  |  FL   | 22222
```

Note, Ste 1 is not part of the address denoted in the OrderLine, it's actually part of the OrderHeader.
How can I write a query to return the data in the desired fashion?  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the SQL you've shown just poorly anonymized? Because it seems to be pulling from `OrderLine` or `OrderHeader` and ignoring `CustomerAddress` in the `ISNULL` statements?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit the question to fix the incorrect alias.  Thanks!

Comment: Your table structures appear to be improperly normalised. Are you able to amend the table structure, so that all the address lines are removed from the order header and are replaced with a single billing address key?

Comment: @MarkBannister You're right, they are improperly normalised, but I am unable to change the underlying table structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't think of a neat way to do this without being quite repetitive.

Assuming the `OL` aliases should have been `CA`:

```
SELECT OH.OrderNo, Item,
       CASE WHEN OL.ShippingAddress IS NULL THEN OH.Line1 ELSE CA.Line1 END,
       CASE WHEN OL.ShippingAddress IS NULL THEN OH.Line2 ELSE CA.Line2 END,
       CASE WHEN OL.ShippingAddress IS NULL THEN OH.City ELSE CA.City END,
       CASE WHEN OL.ShippingAddress IS NULL THEN OH.State ELSE CA.State END,
       CASE WHEN OL.ShippingAddress IS NULL THEN OH.Zip ELSE CA.Zip END
FROM   OrderHeader OH
JOIN   OrderLine OL
ON     OH.OrderNo = OL.OrderNo
LEFT JOIN   CustomerAddress CA
ON     OL.CustNum = CA.CustNum
AND    OL.ShippingAddress = CA.ShippingAddress
```

Comment: I forgot about CASE, thanks!  I think you're right, as the determination of the address fields must be made based on a specific column.